# How can I blur out the background when I open a jQuery tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I have started the work (See jsFidde below), but don't know how to get the background to blur slightly when the tooltip pops up. Is this possible? Or will I have to use a dialog instead? http://jsfiddle.net/EqT4R/

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
    // ???
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd give [this approach](http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/) a try.  There's no native 'blur' effect available.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from blur, I tried with slight different approach.

When tooltip,

- `opens`: I will add the background color
- `closes`: I will remove the background color

### JQuery:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    show: {
        effect: "slideDown",
        delay: 100
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $("body").addClass("customColor");
    },
    close: function( event, ui ) {
        $("body").removeClass("customColor");
    }
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/EqT4R/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this effect with CSS filters:

```
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.noblur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

And also the open() and close() events of the toolip:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#poem").addClass("blur");
        $("#poem").removeClass("noblur");
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $("#poem").removeClass("blur");
        $("#poem").addClass("noblur");
    }
});
```

It turns out that whatever CSS gets applied (eg, .blur) does not get applied to the tooltip, thank goodness. See jsFiddle completed: http://jsfiddle.net/88gNA/

Answer (score 0):

I think I got close to the effect you're looking for by adding `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers to the links that get the tooltips.  When I hover the link, I add an element to the document that fills the page and has CSS transparency.  I set the link to `display: inline-block` and `z-index: 999` so that it stays on top of the new element.  When I move the mouse off of the link, I `.detach()` the new element.

You might be able to get even closer to the desired effect using a png background with a blurry semi-transparent texture instead of a color for the new element.

### CSS:

```
.bgblur {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 800;
    top: -1em;
    right: -1em;
    bottom: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

### JavaScript:

```
$bgblur = $("<div class='bgblur'>");
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();
    $("a[title]").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).css({
            "display": "inline-block",
                "position": "relative",
                "z-index": "999"
        });
        $(this).before($bgblur);
    });
    $("a[title]").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $bgblur.detach();
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/L5TKU/)